# TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Whenever I try to type-hint a list of strings, such as

```
tricks: list[str] = []
```

, I get *TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable*. I follow a course where they use the same code, but it works for them. So I guess the problem is one of these differences between my an the courses environments. I use:

- vs code
- anaconda
- python 3.8.15
- jupyter notebook

Can someone help me fix that?

I used the same code in normal .py files and it sill doesn't work, so that is probably not it.
The python version should also not be the problem as this is kind of basic.
Anaconda should also not cause such Error messages.
Leaves the difference between vscode and pycharm, which is also strange.
Therefore I don't know what to try.

Comment: `list[str] = []` That is not the correct format for a type hint.  Show us your actual code, and the full error message.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help you.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4046632

Comment: `list[str]` is like calling `list.__getitem__(str)`, I.e. literally asking the `list` _class_ (not an instance of it) to lookup something with the key `str` (the string class, itself). That's probably not what you intended.

Comment: @Alexander: `list[str]` is actually [totally valid](https://docs.python.org/3.9/whatsnew/3.9.html#type-hinting-generics-in-standard-collections) on Python 3.9+.

Comment: "In type annotations you can now use built-in collection types such as list and dict as generic types instead of importing the corresponding capitalized types (e.g. List or Dict)" TIL! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @Alexander No, it would be like `type.__getitem__(list, str)`.  Python 3 introduced `__class_getitem__` so that (as far as I can tell) you can define what this syntax means without having to define a special metaclass.

Comment: (Sorry, "no" was too harsh. `list.__getitem_(...)` and `type.__getitem(list, ...)` are basically equivalent, but the reason for providing `__class_getitem__` instead of a single definition of `type.__getitem__` is the same.)

Comment: in later versions of Python you can use `list` in type hints

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're on an old Python version. `list[str]` is only valid [starting in Python 3.9](https://docs.python.org/3.9/whatsnew/3.9.html#type-hinting-generics-in-standard-collections). Before that, you need to use `typing.List`:

```
from typing import List

tricks: List[str] = []
```

If you're taking a course that uses features introduced in Python 3.9, you should probably get a Python version that's at least 3.9, though.

Answer (score 3):

Python 3.8 is trying to subscript list which is of type `type`.
This will work:

```
from typing import List
tricks: List[str] = []
```