# "TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable" when importing library URX python

Tags: python, pycharm, typeerror, python-import

I'm trying to use the library urx in Python, but the import line alone returns error-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/...../mycode.py", line 1, in <module>
    import urx
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\urx\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from urx.urrobot import RobotException, URRobot  # noqa
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\urx\urrobot.py", line 9, in <module>
    from urx import urrtmon
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\urx\urrtmon.py", line 16, in <module>
    import math3d as m3d
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\math3d\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .transform import Transform, PoseVector
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\math3d\transform.py", line 156, in <module>
    class Transform(object):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\math3d\transform.py", line 528, in Transform
    ApTs: typing.Union[np.ndarray, tuple[PositionVector]],
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

I've replaced the interpreter, updated Python, removed the package then reinstalled it...
I have no idea what the problem could be. I searched for similar cases online but couldn't find anything helpful

edit: this is my code:

```
import urx
print("hello")
```

Comment: @KeyboardCat I dont see how... my error is not for using the library- but for simply importing it, my code looks like this: import urx / print("hello")

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75202610/typeerror-type-object-is-not-subscriptable-python)

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I was thinking of the exact same, but isn’t there a subtle difference? OP‘s issue is in a dependency of a dependency, so the main suggested answer of „change the code to something compatible with 3.8“, while technically possible, wouldn’t be my first choice.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a dependency of the library is using a syntax that only works [from Python 3.9 onwards](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75202688/15704972). I'd suggest you create a separate environment, e.g. using conda or mamba, if the libraries you want are available there for Windows - those will try and make the dependencies work out; otherwise you might have to try and pin versions by hand until it works, unfortunately.

Comment: thanks! it's working! I had to reinstall pycharm as well because it thought 3.12 is like 3.1 :')